# android_tutorial_teleop for TurtleBot

Tags: turtlebot, android-core, rosjava-core, android-teleop, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am trying to develop an application for TurtleBot I am trying to run the tutorial from android_core. First of all, the android_tutorial_pubsub seems to work fine as when I enter my master URI the app does respond with Hello World and the timer.

But then I encountered some problem on android_tutorial_teleop. At first when I touch the virtual joystick I received NullPointerException and the app crashes. I somehow fixed it by adding a line guided by one user here. But then even when I move the joystick around, the TurtleBot is unresponsive. Therefore I am wondering where is the problem? Do I have to run some commands first on the TurtleBot laptop and android_tutorial_teleop doesn't work on TurtleBot? I did follow the tutorial on TurtleBot bringup but to no help so far.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45672/android_tutorial_teleop-for-turtlebot/) by [steven7](https://answers.ros.org/users/3213/steven7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First try running the keyboard teleop from a networked computer. That will help ensure your TurtleBot is operating correctly. Then I suggest digging into the system with the roswtf, rosgraph, and rostopic tools to diagnose the issue.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1